# Lost records due to inserting manual data

Tags: mysql

I manually entered 50 records into our database starting at row 600000. My records went up to row 100000 before this insertion. My goal was to separate these records, which I did accomplish, **but I did not know that the auto increment would thus start at 600050 instead of filling in the prior 500,000 records.**

Is there a way to reclaim the 500,000 lost blank records. It seems like a big deal or is it not really a big deal either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your server and application are severely limited which would force you to use a small data type for your auto increment field this is absolutely no big deal.

Edit: just to clarify, you didn't **lose** 500,000 records or waste any space. Your auto increment value is just higher than it would be if those removed records had never existed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to reclaim because you did not lose anything, your auto-increment value is just at a really high number because you manually inserted items with a particular id.

You can change your auto-increment value by doing the following

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = X
```

Comment: didnt seem to do anything. its still inserting in the 600000's